# Как получить возраст пользователя?

Tags: javascript, data-mining

Яндекс Метрика при добавлении своего кода на сайт позволяет получать информацию о возрасте, географии и устройстве.
Какие сервисы позволяют получать эту информацию в режиме реального времени при заходе пользователя на сайт?

Comment: Боюсь, что в режиме реального времени это не получится. Яндекс Метрика узнает возраст уже у себя на сервере, при анализе данных.

Устройство и географию - вы сможете получить сразу же, как пользователь зашёл.

Географию по IP адресу, либо запросив напрямую в браузере. Устройство - распарсив заголовок User-Agent,  navigator.vendor, navigator.platform и т.д.

Comment: Ну география и устройство были всё-таки в меньшем приоритете. Больше всего хотелось аналитику вроде возраста и пола..

Comment: Можно при заходе на сайт спросить возраст пользователя

Comment: @Abmin читайте вопрос. Спасибо кэп

Comment: Какой вопрос, такие и ответы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вопрос довольно сложный.
Для получения таких данных используют сложные алгоритмы основанные на машинном обучении и возможно на искусственном интеллекте использующие большой и актуальный объем информации о пользователях.

Все что остается нам, простым смертным, делать это использовать готовые решения продающие нужную информацию. Их на рынке не так много (особенно в русском сегменте), обычно принято называть их DMP. Из контекста вашего вопроса вам нужна информация по соцдему.

Я знаю несколько поставщиков информации по соцдему - adfox (косвенно можно получить нужную информацию), aidata, CleverDATA, Facetz.DCA (не все они работают в режиме реального времени).

Добавлю еще немного деталей. Все поставщики данных требуют zero pixel matching, т.е. дают ссылку в параметры которой нужно вставить произвольный идентификатор пользователя на стороне площадки, который потом будет использован в api для получения информации о пользователе и в отгружаемых отчетах (по сути это база данных где в качестве ключа фигурирует ваш идентификатор пользователя и вся доступная информация об этом пользователе).

Comment: Конкретизируйтк примеры поставщиков и будет что надо. А так вода водой

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko у каждого поставщика свой способ интеграции перечислять их всех будет довольно сложно. Т.к. они являются заинтересованной стороной то предоставляют у себя на сайте подробную информацию по способам внедрения своего функционала.

Answer (score 17):

Яндекс получает возраст и пол за счет тотальной слежки за пользователями. Работает это примерно так:

- Яндекс скупает данные о предпочтених людей разных групп у маркетинговых агенств.
- Яндекс активно следит за пользователями - анализирует их поисковые запросы, время появления в онлайне - и пытается угадать принадлежность пользователя к конкретной группе.
- При заходе пользователя на ваш сайт Яндекс делится своими догадками с вами.

Об этом прямо сказано в [справке по метрике](https://yandex.ru/support/metrika/visitors/demographics.xml). Механизм назвается Крипта, [на сайте Яндекса есть достаточно подробное описание](https://yandex.ru/company/technologies/crypta/).

Comment: Спасибо, но вы кажется не уловили суть вопроса. Он был не как это делает Яндекс, а как это сделать самим.

Comment: Судя с объяснения можно сделать вывод, что самим такое сделать невозможно.

Comment: Нет, не следует. Более того, такая реализация точно существует. Даже если этот ответ будет единственным, отмечать его правильным не за что. Ответа на вопрос прямого нет

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko вы ждете ответа-ссылки на скрипт, который выдаст вам возраст пользователя? У яндекса есть (или был) Яндекс.Атом, который отдавал данные Крипты в реальном времени. Он вышел пару лет назад в закрытый бета-тест, с тех пор - никаких новостей.

Comment: http://atom.yandex.ru/ сгинул уже

Answer (score 3):

**Google Analytics** позволяет получать эти данные в режиме реального времени при заходе пользователя на сайт

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эм.. Это ответ?

Comment: Это прямой ответ на вопрос =]

Comment: Хм.. Перечитал вопрос... Ладно.

Comment: Насколько я понял, топикастер хотел получить эти данные прямо на стороне сайта, для текущего посетителя/запроса, а не в сторонней системе, с задержкой в несколько секунд.

Comment: Он спрашивал про сервисы

Comment: К сожалению, я видно сформулировал не максимально точно. Речь именно о сервисах к которым можно послать запрос с сайта, в режиме реалтайма определить принадлежность пользователя к одной из соц групп и адаптироваться